# Getting single pixel line contours of jigsaw with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to automatically extract the contour of all the puzzle pieces from a photo of a puzzle. Here's the grayscale input image:

[image: Greyscale image]

So far, I've been able to get to a more helpful image which varies less with the lighting conditions by taking the local standard deviation (standard deviation within an 11px box), and applying a 5px box blur to the result using opencv. That gives me this:

[image]

From here, I'm not sure what to do to get down to a single pixel line between the pieces. Having approximate contours for each individual piece isn't quite good enough, because I want to be able to cut up the image into the pieces and be able to move those pieces independently while the pieces still fit together perfectly.

The results of `findContours` are nowhere near good enough for this.

My ideal output here is to have an image that overlays the original and has a 1px black line between every adjacent pair of pieces.

Comment: Maybe you should take the inverse of the current image(255 -> 0 and 0->255) and than each piece will be separate. Now use findContours to get each peace outline.

Comment: @AmitayNachmani Not sure if I'm interpreting you right, but I'm having a hard time understanding how inverting the image would do anything to separate the pieces if the the pieces aren't already separate.

Comment: Can you please post the image you have after the standard deviation as an image file (not a print screen with axes) and i would see if what i am suggesting make sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

1. Use local threshold for the image thresholding.
2. Remove areas with a small area.
3. Inverse the image (255 - ThreholdImage)
4. Find connected components using findContours.

The result is:
[image]

It is far from prefect but i think this is because i used the image that you gave in the post. I think if you post the original image i will get better results.

Comment: How did you remove areas with a small area?

Comment: You use fincontours and for each contour you calculate the area if the area is smaller than some threshold you filter it.